# How to preview iOS app information before release

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

There were some problems regarding showing the languages on iTunes for our app. It was showing only English, but we added support for Spanish, French, German. We have fixed the issue by adding language projects through XCode, but right now we want to preview how the app information would look without submitting the new version finally. How to preview this data?
Attached is a screenshot from another app to indicate what information we are trying to see.[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "adding language projects"? You do not need to add a new project for each language, you simply add a Localizable.strings file in the corresponding .lproj folder. Select your poject and on the General tab, you can add languages. Then select a strings file or Storyboard and select the languages that you want to translate the file into. Then the app store should show the languages automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on the region/country of your App Store. You should change to Spanish, German, and French for checking.

Check more information from the [link](https://medium.com/@jkkngai/how-to-view-app-store-descriptions-in-a-different-language-on-iphone-or-ipad-78db3711dc37)